# C#: uploading file in worker task with possible introduction of other tasks

Tags: c#, upload, task

Via using c# 4.5.2 I've created a window forms application in which in one of its functions, after gaining data from user (in a register from), saves the data on the disk and also upload a backup of data to my ftp server.

I've implemented the uploading to the ftp server via a task in the background so as to not block user thread. The problem arises when system is uploading the file while another request for upload is coming.

What are the possible solutions here?

- Creating a queue of tasks and process them one at a time?
- lock the saved file so as to prevent other threads from accessing it till the first thread finishes the job?

**Note:** I don't want to block user thread in any way.

Comment: did my answer solve your problem or you are looking for some other info?

Comment: Actually it's a bit hard to grasp

Comment: maybe you post some code and we will try to give the hints?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the concepts of ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent and reading about them

Comment: Read this from the nutshell King Albahari http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_ManualResetEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a good example from Microsoft and they have ManualResetEvent used:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 ManualResetEvent waitObject; 

 // Get the event to wait on.
 waitObject = state.OperationComplete;

 // Asynchronously get the stream for the file contents.
 request.BeginGetRequestStream(
 new AsyncCallback (EndGetStreamCallback), state);
 // Block the current thread until all operations are complete.
 waitObject.WaitOne();

 // The operations either completed or threw an exception.
 if (state.OperationException != null)
 {
  throw state.OperationException;
 }
 else
 {
  Console.WriteLine("The operation completed - {0}", state.StatusDescription);
 }
```

- If you will use a Queue, this apporach will guarantee that the tasks will be executed in a sequential order. First task in first task out.
- Locking is easy in this use case.
- Or you can also use async/await apporach as in this example :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bab3ca92-60ad-41c2-812a-cec48d277a5e/asynchronous-ftp-with-the-new-async-methods?forum=csharpgeneral 
  , Download file you have to implemented by your self.